# How to draw blurred transparent background in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a custom QGraphicsItem class in which I have overriden paint event as below

```
void MyRectangle::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem 
*option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rec = boundingRect();

    //code to fill blured background fill
}
```

I need to fill the rec area with blured transparent effect. So that I can see the background of MyRectangle as blured.

Answer (score 2):

*It is not necessary to reinvent the wheel*, [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) supports [QGraphicsEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html), and within those effects available is [QGraphicsBlurEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsblureffect.html) so you just have to use it:

```
QGraphicsBlurEffect *effect = new QGraphicsBlurEffect;
item->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

Note: If you want to create new effects a proper way is to inherit from `QGraphicsEffect` and overwrite the `draw()` method, so it is not necessary to create a class that implements the same effect for each item.

Comment: This works fine for me if we need to apply the blur effect for entire QGraphicsItem.  My problem is I am using a custom QGraphicsItem in which I overriden the paint event to draw  resizable corner points(basically these are another rectangles in each corner) so that user can click the corner points and resize the item.  Now the issue comes while applying QGraphicsBurEffect, the effect gets applies to corner rectangles also. I don't want to do that. Can we set a specific area to apply the blur effect ?

Comment: @GUI-Novice Do not think it would be easier if you showed the code of your personalized QGraphicsItem, also in this question you do not indicate anything about it, I think that my answer is correct for the requirements of your current question, in the other question I have not dared to post some answer if it would be correct to publish the code of your QGraphicsItem as I said, in addition to images that illustrate what you want.